Flutter Build Error INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-2
When I'm working on my login page i added continue with google. After :
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone16k arm64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk...
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install /Users/username/{Project Path}/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-2]
Error launching application on sdk gphone16k arm64.


I need to get an build completed version of the app

try to specify supported architectures in android/app/build.gradle file
android {
defaultConfig {
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
    }
}

}

Add the following to mainfest android:extractNativeLibs="true" like this
<application
   ............//other settings
   android:extractNativeLibs="true">

